# Form tag is not containing innerHTML

Tags: html, ejs

Ok, so I'm having an issue in my project, summary is: I have a bootstrap modal that has a form in it containing user data to be updated. In said form there is meant to be a h5 heading and an input. The problem is the form tag is closing and putting the contents of said form in the parent element (below it). Source code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        Admin || <%= config.name %>
    </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <%- include("./../components/head.ejs")%>
</head>

<body class="w-100 bg-light-light h-auto">
    <%- include("./../components/nav.ejs")%>
        <div class="float-end content bg-light-light ps-3 pt-3" style="width: 80%;">
            <p class="text-muted">Click on a user to see more.</p>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Username</th>
                            <th scope="col">Rank</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% users.forEach(target=>{%>
                            <tr style="cursor: pointer;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-<%=target.username%>">
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <%= Buffer.from(target.username, 'base64').toString() %>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <%= target.rank %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%= target.name %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-<%=target.username%>" tabindex="-1"
                                aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                                                <%= config.code + Buffer.from(target.username, 'base64').toString() %>
                                            </h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h4>User <%= config.code + Buffer.from(target.username, 'base64').toString() %></h4>
                                            <hr>
<!--HERE=================-->
                                            <form class="form-control" method="POST" action="/admin/reqs/updateUser">

                    <h5>User Options</h5>
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<%= Buffer.from(target.username, 'base64').toString() %>">
                                            </form>
<!--HERE=================-->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <%})%>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/suncalc/1.8.0/suncalc.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-s40QuZdS5wcjdt2OHUWSGRCECWr+YqbvRSaiBpEKOlOsbePPvXreeOTB4SVteinFcc1RpW/uDueEsknm9iJl2g=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However in the browser element view (thingy) it shows this:
[image: browserElView]

This affects all browsers,

send help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `<tr>` elements may be children of `<tbody>` elements.

You are trying to put a `<div>` there (and the `<form>` in deep inside that `<div>`) which isn't allowed.

The error recovery rules the browser is applying to try to repair your error are not giving you a good outcome.

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). Write valid HTML.

Comment: Interesting, because I used it in other pages (not the form tho) and it worked fine, thanks for this however as it fixed it!

Comment: @Samo2120 it was not working fine. the browser was able to fix your html to get the expected results...